# Can not trigger the h:selectonemenu onselect event

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, jsf-2

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="queueSelectMenu" styleClass="selectOneMenue-style" 
    tabindex="1" value="#{reworkQueueMB.queueType}" onselect="alert('2');" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{queueMB.queueSelectItems}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

When I choose the item of the selectmenu, I want to get the `select` event, but it doesn't work. 
 I don't want to use the `change` event, because when I select an item that is already selected, the `change` event will be triggered again.

Comment: @Jigar :<select ... onselect="alert('2');" > 
...</select>

Comment: I have run into this problem before as well and couldn't figure it out.  I notice that it seems to happen with SelectItems and not Strings.

Comment: So you mean , if use selelctItem and string , that problem will be solved .

Comment: `onchange` documentation says: _Javascript code executed when this element loses focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus_. So, in theory, that should not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML DOM `select` event is only triggered when you select (highlight) text in a text input field such as `<input>` and `<textarea>`. But the `<h:selectOneMenu>` renders a HTML `<select>` element, not an `<input>` element. It does not allow you for selecting text in the field. The `select` event does nothing here.

Technically, setting the `click` event on every individual `<option>` element should work out for you.

```xml
<h:form id="formId">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="menuId" value="#{reworkQueueMB.queueType}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{queueMB.queueSelectItems}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <script>
        $("[id='formId:menuId'] option").click(function() {
            alert("2");
        });
    </script>
    ...
```

However, this does (unsurprisingly) **not** work in any IE browser, even not IE9.

Your best bet is really the `change` event. This is fully crossbrowser. A completely different alternative is to use a radiobutton group instead -which can be rendered by `<h:selectOneRadio>`. The `click` event should do exactly what you want.

```xml
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{reworkQueueMB.queueType}" onclick="alert('2')">
    <f:selectItems value="#{queueMB.queueSelectItems}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: Thanks.I benefit a lot from you.